# Is there a way to monitor if Data was inserted Manually into the database versus via a system (like ef core)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, monitoring

This might be a silly question, I have done some research on database triggers and found them extremely useful in monitoring changes to the database. This is the script I found for monitoring creation, altering and changes of a similar nature in a database:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChangeLog](
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectName] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectType] [VARCHAR](25) NOT NULL,
    [SqlCommand] [VARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] [VARCHAR](256) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
 
ALTER TABLE [Admin].[ChangeLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_EventsLog_EventDate]  
            DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [EventDate]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 
CREATE TRIGGER [backup_objects]
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_PROCEDURE, 
    ALTER_PROCEDURE, 
    DROP_PROCEDURE,
    CREATE_TABLE, 
    ALTER_TABLE, 
    DROP_TABLE,
    CREATE_FUNCTION, 
    ALTER_FUNCTION, 
    DROP_FUNCTION,
    CREATE_VIEW,
    ALTER_VIEW,
    DROP_VIEW
AS
 
SET NOCOUNT ON
 
DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA() 

INSERT INTO changelog(databasename, eventtype, 
    objectname, objecttype, sqlcommand, loginname)
VALUES(
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'),
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 
@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
)
GO
 
ENABLE TRIGGER [backup_objects] ON DATABASE
GO
```

However I need to see if someone has manually inserted data into the database, via a script or via the 'Edit top 200 rows'. If someone could provide some insight with regards to this it would be really useful.

Comment: You could add an extra column to hold that information. But make sure users can't modify it manually.

Comment: I think this isn't possible on the database itself. But in your application, you can log each time data is entered into the database. In this way, you can find out all the data entered by the application.

Comment: Unfortunately if I do it that way I'll have unnecessary amount of data. The problem is client has access to the db and we can't control what they do. We can't lock them out .. but we have to know when they add data manually through the ssms